# How to make Aptana Studio run with Google chrome?

Tags: html, macos, aptana

I have a Macbook Pro with OS X 10.7.4. Recently i installed Aptana Studio 3 from the Aptana website. When i tried to run my HTML code with chrome, i did not find any option. No option for Opera either. There is only one option for firefox. Someone please tell me how should i run them ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Chrome Web Browser manually:

1. Open the 'Run' (the green arrow one) Button and choose 'Run configurations..' from menu.
2. Click on the 'Web Browser' list item
3. Click the 'New Launch configuration' button
4. Browse for Chrome's executable: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
5. Name your new config, i called it 'Chrome', clever isnt it?
6. Click the 'Apply' button to save changes.

You should now see Chrome on the Run menu.

Regards